# What protocol is used to upload documents on SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, document, file-upload

Little bit a stupid question :)

When users are uploading documents to SharePoint over what protocol is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You will get your answer for protocol from below mentioned link by MSDN

[SharePoint Protocols Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg134031.aspx)

**Update**

If you are asking about the method, then it converts all files to BLOB type & stores that information to database. There is no physical file to be stored in SharePoint Server.

Comment: I already saw that page, before I created question. I didn't find appropriate answer there. I want to know whether files are uploading over HTTP, FTP, SMTP? Am a novice in these waters so I am asking for straight answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know that files are stored on SQLs :)

Comment: Kindly check my updated answer as well as this link...`http://sharepoint1on1.blogspot.in/2012/10/where-are-my-documents-stored-have-you.html`

Comment: I get this message. Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. Thank you on your time and effort. I will check online little bit more.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/sharepoint-2010-storing-documents-on-the-file-system-with-remote-blob-storage/

Comment: http://sharepoint1on1.blogspot.in/2012/10/where-are-m‌​y-documents-stored-h‌​ave-you.html

Comment: Happy to help you. :)